# Is there a better way to access the last element in a for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, coding-efficiency

[edited the post to be more clear]
The code below is supposed to represent a number of trial runs, and within each trial assume a is the number of cases that need to be checked.

```
while(testCaseAmt > 0) {
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
   if(some condition)
   //code when i is not the last element
   //then I would like to break/return here.
   if(i = a - 1)
   //code when i is the last element
   //then if the above if statement never runs during the a amt of trials
   //i will print out something else
   }

   testCaseAmt--;
   }
```

My question is if there is another way to access specifically the last element within a for loop to give it specific instructions. I want to loop through a set trials and if they meet the first condition, I stop the loop immediately and return. However, if the condition isn't found I still need to print out not found.

Cheers.

Comment: To simply access the last element of let's say a String Array named **myArray**: `String myVar = myArray[myArray.length - 1];`. If **a** is just an Integer value as you show then: `int i = a;` since if **a** was an Array you would of had: `for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { .... }`.

Comment: Also, in your example you are assigning the result of `a - 1` to `i`. If you want to use the loop from your example, it should be `if (i == a.length - 1)`

Comment: guys I don't think this is just about arrays....

Comment: @LalitVerma I think that post is relevant, but I'm asking how to say in code when I'm at the last iteration of a loop, I want to do something different then what the loop was already doing for the previous iterations.

Comment: just break your loop using break before coming to last element and do whateever you want

Comment: or loop till **i<a-1**

Comment: @DevilsHnd I edited my post to make it more clear what I'm trying to ask

Answer (score 2):

To me this seems related to "off-by-one errors" or "fencepost errors", see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

If the code you're executing when `i` is not the last element isn't too complex, it could be better to just end the `for` loop one iteration earlier and write the specific code for the last element outside the `for` loop.

Adding an `if` statement inside a `for` loop where you know it will only be true at the very last iteration could be seen as bad-style.

Comment: I edited my post if you could take another look thanks

Comment: When an element is not the last one, i.e. not `a - 1`, you have a `return/break` statement if it meet some condition. Does that mean if a single element (not last) passes your test, you don't want/need to test the last one?

Comment: Yeah, if a condition is met, the loop is done and it doesn't matter what the other trials are. It's almost like an if else statement but I can't use else because it would print out more than one statement if that makes sense.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure what the exact condition you are testing, but if the condition you are testing for non-last elements and the last-element is the same, you could perhaps move the `if (i = a - 1)` code block inside the first `if (some condition)` test. If that wouldn't work in your case, then the way it is currently seems fine as well. Sorry, It's a bit hard to make a judgement without seeing the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `boolean conditionMet = false` before the for-loop and iterate until `i < a-1`. 
If `some condition` applies, execute your code, then set `conditionMet = true` and break out of the for-loop. 
After the for-loop, check if `!conditionMet` and in this case, execute the code for the last element.